# bouncing image with tk?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

i cannot figure out how to add an image to this tk window someone pls explain like im 5 because im actually dumb af when it comes to coding all this code is stolen from other people

```
import random
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
x = random.randint(7,20)
y = random.randint(7,20)
h = random.randint(200,300)
w = random.randint(200,300)
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.velx = x
        self.vely = y
        self.pos = (250,250)
        self.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}+{self.pos[0]}+{self.pos[1]}")
        self.configure(background='#29a32d')

        self.image = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\semih\Downloads\_7OPS.png")
        Label(self, image=self.image).pack()

        
    def moveWin(self):
        x = self.pos[0] + self.velx
        y = self.pos[1] + self.vely
        downx, downy = x+self.width, y+self.height
        sWidth = self.winfo_screenwidth()  # gives 1366
        sHeight = self.winfo_screenheight()  # gives 1080
        if x <= 0 or downx >= sWidth:
            self.velx = -self.velx
        if y <= 0 or downy >= sHeight:
            self.vely = -self.vely
        self.pos = (x,y)
        self.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
        return [x, y, downx, downy]
    
root = Window()

def move():
    root.moveWin()
    root.after(10, move)
move()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code (my answer to your another similar question) has put an image in the window, so what is the problem actually?

Comment: it simply does not work for me and i have no idea why

Comment: Try changing `"C:\Users\semih\Downloads\_7OPS.png"` to `r"C:\Users\semih\Downloads\_7OPS.png"` (raw string) or `"C:\\Users\\semih\\Downloads\\_7OPS.png"` (double backslash) or `"C:/Users/semih/Downloads/_7OPS.png"` (use forward slash, Python supports it even in Windows platform).  Your code works for me after such change.

Comment: It works now but is it possible to make the window resize to the image automatically?  and/or make it get the/an image from the web?

Comment: If you want the window has the same size of the image, don't call `.geometry()`.